# Sending a message from raspberry pi to android app

Tags: android, websocket, raspberry-pi3

What I am trying to do is that when a GPIO button is pressed on raspberry pi, a notification should be displayed by my android app. I read that this can be implemented using Firebase Cloud Messaging or any other cloud messaging service. But this is too slow for my requirement and this needs an internet connection. Then I came across Websockets.Here are my requirements:

- Both Pi and android phone are connected to the same network.
- I need communication over local network without internet.
- Raspberry Pi needs to send the message; Android app only receives messages.

Does Websocket fit my requirements? Can it be used for implementing the required setup? If so which one should be client and which one should be server?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use normal sockets for it. Its irrelevant which device is the server. But if you let the raspi be the client then you dont need a permanent connection.

Comment: @greenapps can you please elaborate? I'm new to network programming. Please point to some tutorials regarding sockets. It will be of great help.

Comment: Google for client-server examples.